# Google Drive API Q logic clauses order

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

So I was having a problem while trying to list certain files from my drive, the original code was:

```
var request = _DriveService.Files.List();
request.Q = $"name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName0}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName1}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName2}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName3}'" +
        " and trashed = false" +
        $" and '{Properties.Settings.Default.MyParents[0]}' in parents";
request.Fields = "files(id, name, parents)";
var files = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

The problem was that it returned 12 files, instead of 4 files. After a bit or testing and tweaking I realized that google drive was ignoring the `and` clauses, so it was retrieving all the removed files.

Now, with this code it works like a charm:

```
var parentsTrashed = $"and '{Properties.Settings.Default.Myparents[0]}' in parents and trashed = false";
var request = _DriveService.Files.List();
request.Q = $"name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName0}' {parentsTrashed}" +
    $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName1}' {parentsTrashed}" +
    $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName2}' {parentsTrashed}" +
    $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName3}' {parentsTrashed}";
request.Fields = "files(id, name, parents)";
var files = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

So the `and`s and `or`s clauses needs to be in this order: `(name and and and) OR (name and and and) OR ...`.

I can't find any indication of this in the documentation nor around the internet: **is it a bug or is it intended? Shouldn't it be noted down in the documentation or is it and I just didn't found it, or is it a standard thing that I didn't know about till now (I'm an amateur)?**

Comment: I am leaning towards bug.  But i pinged someone at Google see if he responds he will know better.

Comment: I would at least suggest using brackets to make your intended precedence clear. It's possible that it's testing it as `name = name1 or name = name2 or name = name3 or (name = name4 and trashed = false and parentid in parents)` I suspect you want `(name = name1 or name = name2 or name = name3 or name = name4) and trashed = false and parentid in parents`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I thought that possibility too, but I didn't realize that I could use brackets :oops. Then maybe this would work too: `(name = name1 or name2 = name2) and trashed = false and parentid in parents` ? I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it works... we wrote it at the same time. It's much better this way. I'll note it down, ty.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know the specific rules for operator precedence in Drive queries, it would *at least* make it easier to read if you specified what you mean using brackets:

```cs
var request = _DriveService.Files.List();
request.Q = $"(name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName0}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName1}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName2}'" +
        $" or name = '{Properties.Settings.Default.SomeFileName3}')" +
        " and trashed = false" +
        $" and '{Properties.Settings.Default.MyParents[0]}' in parents";
request.Fields = "files(id, name, parents)";
var files = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

That way the query will be of the form:

```
(name = name1 or name = name2 or name = name3 or name = name4)
and trashed = false and parentid in parents
```

(Without line breaks, of course.)

I suspect in your current query, it's effectively:

```
name = name1 or name = name2 or name = name3 or
(name = name4 and trashed = false and parentid in parents)
```

Comment: And yes. Most curious is that I didn't even think of trying brackets. I don't know why O_o It happens I suppose.

Comment: For clarification drive q parm uses https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages so this is not a bug

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention brackets (parentheses), https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#operators, but it works.